# AngularJS $stateProvider loads parent but not child template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I just started migrating to AngularJS and I'm already having problems with the `$stateProvider` from the [angular-ui/ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) framework. This is what I have so far:

```
angular
    .module('testApp', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index/home");

        $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                abstract: true,
                url: "/index",
                template: "parent"
            })
            .state('index.home', {
                url: "/home",
                template: "child"
            })
    })
    .controller("MainController", function() {
    })
```

Now, running this script redirects me to `http://example.com/#/index/home` but it only displays the *parent* string on the page. The *child* string is not being shown. From my understanding this should load the first template because we are on the `/#/index` domain part and then the second because we are on a nested page `/#/index/home`.

Can someone help me and explain why this is not working as intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your template for the parent you need another `<div ui-view></div>` in order to render child states.

If you want multiple nested views, you can have multiple `ui-view` in your parent template. You just have to name them. For example,

parent template:

```
<h1>parent</h1>
<div ui-view="child1"></div>
<div ui-view="child2"></div>
```

And you define the child states as follows:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/index",
            template: "parent"
        })
        .state('index.home', {
            url: "/home",
            views: {
             'child1': {
               templateURL: "child1.html"
              }
            }
        })
        .state('index.home2', {
          url: '/home2',
          views: {
           'child2': {
             templateURL: 'child2.html'
          }
          }
        })
```

*note I used templateURL instead of template. Assuming your app has modular file structure.